# Magento 1.9 cron maximum execution time exceeded

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, magento-cron

I've got custom module to generate feeds for google shopping and others.

When i'm running from magento cron i've got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 1800 seconds exceeded in...
```

but if i check the php option i've got this:

```
[root@mail ~]# /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php -i | grep max_execution_time
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
```

and i can't find 1800 value in any php.ini in the server.

So where cron.php get this value for max_execution_time?

Comment: First check your htaccess file and then php.ini.

Comment: in htaccess php_value max_execution_time 18000